# Unity & Prism Modularity - Load problems

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, unity-container

I need your help again please. I am working on a application with a modular concept.

I want to use Prism and Unity for it. I have looked at the quickstart example from Prism and I also read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) on MSDN.

My actual code looks like:

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return this.Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        var window = this.Shell as Window;
        if (window != null)
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow = window;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The shell has to be a window.");
        }
    }


    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
    } 
}
```

My config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="modules" 
             type="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Prism"/>
  </configSections>
  <modules>
    <module assemblyFile="Modules/MyApp.Module1.dll"
            moduleType="MyApp.Module1.Module1Module, MyApp.Module1"
            moduleName="Module1" />
  </modules>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I have now two problems, the first is that the catalog is not loaded right.
For me it seems that the load method is not being called, or something like that.

The second problem is a consequence of the first I think, that the initialize method in my module is not called.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken your code as is in a Desktop Prism project, but it works as expected.

Somewhere in your application, you will need (at minimum):

```
var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
bootstrapper.Run();
```

I believe for the config section, the default is for modules to load on startup, so as soon as the Bootstrapper runs, your module should be loaded and initialized. This is exactly what happens for me locally.

This is what my module "initialization" looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;

namespace MyApp.Module1
{
    class Module1Module : IModule
    {
        public void Initialize()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

One last thing to check would be to see if it can find the `MyApp.Module1.dll` in the directory it's looking in, but you would get a `ModuleTypeLoadingException` after a  `FileNotFoundException` first-chance exception if this wasn't the case.

**Edit:** here is [the complete source code](http://www.subbot.net/personal/external/stackoverflow/PrismSandbox.zip) for the test solution I made. I cannot think of any differences that make it work for me, but not for you. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for response.
Sorry forgot to post my App.xaml.cs code. I override the on Startup and there i start my bootstrapper.
My Module class is mostly the same like yours, i have only another test string :-)
Annd finally yes the file is in the right folder and i dont get any exception.

But it still does not work.

Comment: @Sukram: That's pretty much what I did as well, I've zipped up the solution's source code, because I cannot think of anything I may have done differently.

Comment: @ Thorarin: Thanks for your code, i don't find any deifferneces to my one but it works. I build up a new project based on your classes and now it works fine. Thanks for your help and your code example.