# Unity & Prims Modularity - using libraries in modules

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, unity-container

i need again help by building a application with modularly concept.
I use unity and prism for it and configure it via App.config, like you can see in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774171/unity-prims-modularity-loads-problems) from me.

Now i want to load usercontrols from a moudle using IRegionViewRegistry from Prism.
It works as long as i not use controls libraries in my usercontrol for example.
Then he get an error that he is unable to find the dll.

Some addtional information:

My folder structure looks like that:

- application folder

  - Modules folder

    - Special folder for each module

My idea was to copy the module dll and the needed libraries to one specail folder. So that he will find the needed dlls right to itselfs location.

And i set local copy to ture by the references for my needed dlls?

Can anybodey help me?

### Edit:

If i copy the libraries next to my exe it works.

But i prefer a solution to copy it next to my module. Anybody a idea for me?

Comment: have you tried setting copy local to true for your dll's?

Comment: yeah i did, but still the same result